# How do I convert between Oracle "Fix versions" and Oracle JDK versions?

Tags: java, java-8

We are affected by the following bug. We use the Oracle JDK but the OpenJDK JIRA is also tracking it:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075484

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8075484

On the Oracle website (bugs.java.com link above) it is stated as being fixed in "Fix version 9 (b137)". Clicking the link on "b137" takes me to a download page for Java 8u121 but this is simply the latest java release.

How do I find out which JDK version (8u121, 8u112, 8u45 etc) corresponds to the strange looking version given in the bug report, "9 (b137)"?

Perhaps it's saying the bug will be fixed in Java 9, and the link just goes to the wrong place?

Comment: you're last phrase is correct, it's just a linkage problem probably.

Comment: damn, so it's not actually going to be fixed in java 8? that would be a shame...

Comment: There is a distinct issue number for each major version that will get a fix. These are linked in the “Backports” section which thankfully includes the “Fix Version” column, so you don’t even have to open the linked issue. So yes, `9b137` means Java 9, beta 137, but the backport shows `8u152`, which means Java 8, update 152… But its ETA is 2017-10-16, which might imply that you want to try a beta of that update in-between…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [jira bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075484), you can see:

> Backports
>
> ```
> Issue Fix Version Assignee    Priority    Status  Resolution  Resolved In Build
> JDK-8172578   8u152   Vyom Tewari P3  Resolved    Fixed   b01
> ```

So the fix should be included in Java 8u152, which is not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

The early access version of JDK 8u152 is available at https://jdk8.java.net/download.html , may be you can download and verify if the fix works for you.